# How to black out everything outside the 2 lines

Tags: opencv, line

I had just used the hough transform (opencv sample Cpp )on below original image to detect lines.
but I want to blackout everything outside the 2 lines...

after houghtransform

[image: http://postimg.org/image/zd81qogjt/]

Actually I want between two lines it should be original image and rest should be blackout,
like this...

[image: http://postimg.org/image/vwitkadv7/]

how to do this.....

Answer (score 0):

You can copy range of rows defined by your lines to dst image filled with zeros.

```
   A(Range::all(),Range(X1,X2)).copyTo(B(Range::all(),Range(X1,X2)));
```

You can use method Mat::copyTo(OutputArray m, InputArray mask); Create mask binary image and draw you rectangle on it. Then copy one to enother using the mask:

```
A.copyTo(B,mask);
```

Or fill Ranges of rows before first line, and after second line.
For example:

```
A(Range::all(),Range(0,X1))=0;
A(Range::all(),Range(X2,A.cols))=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

well how to do in below houghtransform sample program,.

```
vector<Vec2f> lines;
HoughLines(dst, lines, 1, 2*CV_PI/180, 70, 0, 0 );
for( size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++ )
{
    float rho = lines[i][0], theta = lines[i][1];
    Point pt1, pt2;
    double a = cos(theta), b = sin(theta);
    double x0 = a*rho, y0 = b*rho;
    pt1.x = cvRound(x0 + 1000*(-b));
    pt1.y = cvRound(y0 + 1000*(a));
    pt2.x = cvRound(x0 - 1000*(-b));
    pt2.y = cvRound(y0 - 1000*(a));
    line( src, pt1, pt2, Scalar(0,0,255), 3, CV_AA);
}
```

any help......